# Почему array_map выдает Warning?

Tags: php

Застрял на простейшем скрипте, хочу уже разобраться с array_map

```
$matches[1] = array_map("add_domain", $matches[1]);

...

function add_domain($item)
   {
   return 'http://berserktcg.ru?replay=/replays/show/10/'.$item;
   }
```

Выдает **Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'add_domain' not found or invalid function name in** ...

vardump($matches[1]):

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(13) "1023155_26616" [1]=> string(13) "1023155_26616" }
```

Где моя ошибка?
P.S. PHP Version 5.4.16

Comment: Вы используете эту функцию внутри класса?

Comment: Вызываете функцию которая дкларируется после ее вызова.$matches[1] = array_map("add_domain", $matches[1]); напишите после создания функции

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan вы не правы, в PHP сложный интерпретатор компилирующего типа, который парсит весь файл, а потом его исполняет, вызов функции не зависит от места ее объявления в файле.

Comment: @Firepro function 'add_domain' not found .... Видимо очень сложный раз не заметил декларацию

Comment: Странно, но @Vanya Avchyan похоже прав, хотя файл простейший, вот полный листинг https://pastebin.com/hMm9TbcN , если я переношу функцию вверх - оно работает. Оформите как ответ, а всем остальным плюсанул за участие в обсуждении.

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov уберите вообще функцию из if, ее там быть не должно! Проблема в том, что PHP обрабатывает код последовательно, но перед этим выполняет линковку всех доступных функций в глобальном контексте, а функции в if выполняются последовательно, так как интерпретатор не знает определять ли их или нет.

Comment: Уже убрал и плюсанул за наводку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предполагаю,что вы случайно загнали обьявление функции, в какой-нить блок if. К сожалению, есть подобная возможность писать следующие конструкции в PHP:

```
if (1!=1) {
    function test() {
        echo 1;
    }
}
```

Следовательно вызвать функцию test в указанном случае не получится, так как ее определение возможно только при наступлении условия.

Проверьте, что функция **не находится в какой-либо подобной управляющей конструкции**. Приведенный вами код исполняется корректно, при условии конечно, что $matches[1] это массив, иначе требуется передавать просто $matches.

Answer (score 2):

Да вeрно подметил товарищ @GlebKemarsky,и походу обсуждения тоже были в правильном направлении.

Но самым универсальным способом является: В вашем примере переставить ее выше чем то место где она вызывается.Чтоб не была заключена ни в какoм блокe условий.

```
<?php
//самое начало файла 
function add_domain($item)
{
     return 'http://berserktcg.ru?replay=/replays/show/10/'.$item;
}

.....

$matches[1] = array_map("add_domain", $matches[1]);
```

Comment: `Функции не обязаны быть определены до их использования, исключая тот случай, когда функции определяются условно` http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Да блин косяк.Просто так никогда не извращался вот и пропустил мимо ушей.Скорее всего там какое то условие стоит.Обновил ответ

Comment: В комментариях к вопросу есть ссылка на код, в котором функция лежит внутри условного оператора, а [вот ответ, который предлагает это проверить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/660569/208926).

Comment: Да действительно  лучше его декларировать гарантированно а потом хочешь используй хочешь нет

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Эту ссылку не мне надо показывать, а в своём ответе я был честен и показал свой подход,который изначально был верным и понятливей автору вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вы используете функцию внутри класса, тогда Вам следует вызывать `array_map` таким образом:

`array_map($this->add_domain(), $matches);`

Кроме того, `array_map` в Ваше случае не сработает, так как вторым параметром функции должен быть массив, а у вас его элемент (строка).

Comment: увы, но это отдельный маленький скрипт.